# Weight assignment to define an objective function

Tags: c, optimization, weighted, simulated-annealing, objective-function

I have a set of jobs with execution times (C1,C2...Cn) and deadlines (D1,D2,...Dn). Each job will complete its execution in some time, i.e,
 response time (R1,R2,....Rn). However, there is a possibility that not every job will complete its execution before its deadline. So I define a variable called Slack for each job, i.e., (S1,S2,...Sn). Slack is basically the difference between the deadline and the response time of jobs, i.e.,

S1=D1-R1
S2=D2-R2, .. and so on

I have a set of slacks [S1,S2,S3,...Sn]. These slacks can be positive or negative depending on the deadline and completion time of tasks, i.e., D and R.

The problem is I need to define weights (W) for each job (or slack) such that the job with negative slack (i.e., R>D, jobs that miss deadlines) has more weight (W) than the jobs with positive slack and based on these weights and slacks I need to define an objective function that can be used to maximize the slack.

The problem doesn't seem to be a difficult one. However, I couldn't find a solution. Some help in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to d with programming but theory of scheduling tasks.

Comment: Show the code you already have. It should at least read the input and arrange it in some accessable form, mabe have some preparatory processing, like sorting. As it is the question looks more like a request for a free code writing service.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your comments I am not asking to write a code for me but to have some directions how can I assign weights to each jobs. Since slacks can be positive or negative and of different magnitudes. So how can I normalize the slacks and then define the weight for each slack according to its value.

Answer (score 0):

This can often be done easily with **variable splitting**:

```
splus(i) - smin(i) = d(i) - r(i)
splus(i) ≥ 0, smin(i) ≥ 0
```

If we have a term in the objective so that we are minimizing:

```
sum(i, w1 * splus(i) + w2 * smin(i) )
```

this will work ok: we don't need to add the complementarity condition `splus(i)*smin(i)=0`.